# OR_PMCR_20 ERROR IN Google play console account creating

Tags: android, google-play-console

I am trying to create google play console account but the payment through Axis International Debit Card keeps on failing and showing error OR_PMCR_20.
Please find attached screenshot link for the same.
Pls help me to resolve this error.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Click on `form` and upload a photoscan of your passport, also they may refuse the card if it was issued outside your account country.
[image]